# Is there any dharma Shastra that we can use now?

Tags: dharma, time

Is there any dharma Shastra that we can you in mordern days like these days?

Comment: @Rickross even manu Smriti was written in Kali-yuga. But no one follows it

Comment: Manu Smriti exists from Satya Yuga. It is primarily meant to be applicable in Satya Yuga. Who told you that it's written in Kali Yuga? And yes most people don't follow scriptures nowadays.

Comment: @Rickross **The metrical text is in Sanskrit, is variously dated to be from the 2nd century BCE to 3rd century CE**, and it presents itself as a discourse given by Manu (Svayambhuva) and Bhrigu on dharma topics such as duties, rights, laws, conduct, virtues and others. Satya Yuga happened before Mahabharata. And Mahabharata is dated to 3000 BC so how can manu Smriti be for saty yaga

Comment: From the answer linked above its clear that Manu recalls the laws at the beginning of each Kalpa. "The author of the Veda there is none ; (he) the fourfaced (God), at each succeeding revolution of a Kalpa, recalls to mind the Veda ; and so does Manu remember the law (at each succeeding revolution of a Kalpa)"

Comment: Whose opinions are you quoting? Those of sceptics and Indologists? According to Hindu scriptures Manu Smriti exists from the beginning of creation.

Comment: @Rickross yes it is from wiki

Comment: @Rickross indologist are expert in their field. They are professional we can trust them

Comment: Okay you trust them.

Comment: @Rickross what's wrong in trusting them

Comment: I can only tell you what's there in Hindu scriptures. I'm not interested in a discussion on sceptics and indologists.

Comment: @Rickross okay thanks

Comment: @Rickross which book is the source of "According to Hindu scriptures Manu Smriti exists from the beginning of creation." can you explain

Comment: I have given a link of a post in one of the above comments. Did you read my answer there? according to Parshara Smriti, Manu recalls the laws (known as Manu Smriti) at the beginning of each Kalpa. That means Manu Smriti exists since the beginning.

Comment: @DarkKnight I knew you would not read, but Rickross clearly explained in your Shruti law book answer about the beginning and all. I tell you water is colourless and tasteless. But if you want to prove Vodka is water you will say water is colourless but not tasteless. Do they know what’s there in 2nd century BC? —>Time of the Mauryan empire as per their own dating. (As per traditional Hindu dating it’s the Gupta era) You mean to say Swayambhuva Manu existed at the time of Ashoka and Chandragupta (CM)? Humans Ashoka and CM came before progenitor of human race? Please search for water not vodka.